# Error when install cordova on windows 8.1. Help me

Tags: android, cordova, cross-platform

I've installed cordova with commands, it had a problem while installing, cmd displayed the rotating cursor and nothing happened, I have waited for hours. I don't know what is happening, then i created a project, it's OK
but had a error when i built it:

> "Assets directory "C\windows..." does not exit!

It's image of this error : 
[image: error]

I think that is due to installation of cordova. but i don't known how to solve this.
Please help me solve this error. Thank all :((